# Is it due to operator precedence?

Tags: c++, syntax, operator-precedence, post-increment

I have the code below:

```cpp
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<numeric>

using namespace std;

int maxScore(vector<int>& cardPoints, int k) {
    if(k==cardPoints.size()) return accumulate(cardPoints.begin(), cardPoints.end(), 0);

    int endSum=accumulate(cardPoints.begin()+(cardPoints.size()-k), cardPoints.end(), 0);
    int maxValue=endSum;
    int i=0;
    int j=cardPoints.size()-k;

    while(i<k && j<cardPoints.size()) {
        endSum-=cardPoints[j++]+cardPoints[i++];   //-> will change this line
        maxValue=max(maxValue, endSum);
    }

    return maxValue;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v={100,40,17,9,73,75};
    cout<<maxScore(v, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is: `157`.
However, if I change the line commented above as:

```
endSum=endSum-cardPoints[j++]+cardPoints[i++];
```

the output I get is `248`.  Live examples [here](http://cpp.sh/7lppy) and [here](http://cpp.sh/7geje) respectively.  I don't think I am doing anything different in the two statements above.  I *think* it might be due to the post increment operations for `i` and `j`.  Since all of them execute on a single line, I am unable to use any print statements to debug.

Could someone please point out why I am getting a different output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
a -= b + c;
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = a - (b + c);
```

or

```
a = a - b - c;
```

which is *not* the same as:

```
a = a - b + c;
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> endSum -= cardPoints[j++] + cardPoints[i++];
> ```

The equivalent statement with `=` would be:

```
endSum = endSum - (cardPoints[j++] + cardPoints[i++]);
```

or

```
endSum = endSum - cardPoints[j++] - cardPoints[i++];
```